# Android Google Map: How to Draw pin which have text like (1,2,3,4,5..etc)?

Tags: android, android-maps

[image]

I need to show the text inside pins which I draw on map how can I implement this in android any idea please provide me any suggestion for this. For drawing the pin I am using MyItemized overlay class. below is the code for my class..

```
public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    public MyItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context ctx) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));

    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    public void clear() {

        mOverlays.clear();
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mOverlays.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        if (!shadow) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks..

Comment: I didn't try that but you may want to draw text over the canvas coming as parameter in `draw()` method.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Any sample code suggested for doing this using canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do something like this and adjust position and size of text as per your convenience

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) 
{

super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
    int n = size();
    Projection proj = mapView.getProjection();
    Point out;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(20);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
    GeoPoint geoPoint = mOverlays.get(i).getPoint();
    out = new Point();
        proj.toPixels(geoPoint, out);
    canvas.drawText("" + i, out.x, out.y, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: although it's working fine for writing the text but only the problem which i am facing is it's not incremented the value of "n" on pin. How can I do this please help me thanks..

Comment: its my mistake, just change n with i in canvas.drawText("" + n, out.x, out.y, paint);

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply I different drawable for each 'ItemizedOverlay'.

Either that or override that 'ItemizedOverlay's' drawing method and draw the number over a drawable?

For the dynamic drawing of the itemised overlay follow [this](http://deckjockey.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/android-baloon-display-on-map.html) tutorial. Even though its a balloon callout, you can customise it so it suits you.

Comment: Actually i am showing the dynamic data and the length of data may be 10,000 or above so in your case I need to design 10,000 different icons which is not proper, How can I do this dynamically?

Comment: See above for tutorial on dynamic overlay